# Is there any reason for Eclipse showing assignment variables in while loops as valid?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been punked numerous times while working on Java in eclipse when I write a while loop like so:

```
while (recsFinished = true)
```

When in reality I wanted

```
while (recsFinished == true)
```

It's a pretty simple mistake, but it happens to me a lot and it totally throws off the program. And the reason it does is because Eclipse doesn't even throw up a warning when I write the assignment as opposed to the equality equation. This leads me to believe there has to be some reason for a while loop with an assignment equation to exist, but why? I can't think of a single use!

Comment: Stop comparing boolean to true (or false), and you won't be hit again: `while (recsFinished)`

Comment: Ohh, that's a much better way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not just while loops btw. Making an assignment to a variable (or lvalue) in a method call is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such assignments are popular in C and C++ (particularly within `if` statments) and have found themselves part of Java too.

Some folk put the literal on the left hand side: `while (true == recsFinished)` instead and I'm tempted to suggest that you adopt this programming style only that I personally find it obfuscating. This will issue a *compiler* error if `=` is used by accident.

Note well though that comparison to `true` is redundant. Drop it entirely and use `while (recsFinished)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It compiles, since it's valid Java syntax.

It's equivalent to :

```
recsFinished = true;
while (recsFinished) {
    ....
    recsFinished = true;
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
recsFinished = true;
while (true) {
    ....
    recsFinished = true;
}
```

which would give you an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to set a value in the expression of you while loop. If you do this your expression will be evaluated which is alway true because you reset it to true everytime you do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, the operator `=` return the assigned value after calling it.
whcih means if you want to assign a variable in every iteration and the value of this variable is the condition then you will use `=` in the loop condition instead of `==`

**Example**

```
boolean a, b;
b = true;
while(a = b){
    // Some crazy things using a & b
    // loop ends when b == false at the end of an iteration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question; It's valid because the specification says so.

You can call a method with an expression,

> [15.12. Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)
>
> A method invocation expression is used to invoke a class or instance method.
>
> ```
> MethodInvocation:
>    MethodName ( ArgumentList opt )
>
> ArgumentList:
>    Expression
>    ArgumentList , Expression
> ```

and an assignment is an expression,

> [15.26. Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)
>
> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically right-associative (they group right-to-left). Thus, a=b=c means a=(b=c), which assigns the value of c to b and then assigns the value of b to a.
>
> ```
> AssignmentExpression:
>    ConditionalExpression
>    Assignment
> ```